# fwrite - need a new line after variable - PHP

Tags: php

When my script writes to the file, it doesn't break the added content onto a new line.

```
Instead of:
user1:password1
user2:password2

It writes:
user1:password1user2:password2
```

Originally, my fwrite looked like this fwrite($fh, $data); and from searching other questions, I changed my code to this:

```
fwrite($fh, $data . "\n");
```

This does not seem to work though.

Here is my code

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 

$username = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$confirmpw = $_POST['confirmpw'];
$username = strtolower($username);


//Check if passwords match
if ($password != $confirmpw){
print "Passwords do not match, please try again.";
}
else{
//the data
$data = "$username:$password\n";

//open the file and choose the mode

$fh = fopen("passwd.txt", "a+");

// Cycle through the array
$match_found = false;

while (($buffer = fgets($fh, 4096)) !== false)
{
// Parse the line
list($usercheck, $passwordcheck) = explode(':', $buffer);
if (trim($usercheck) == $username)
{
    print "The username is already in our system.  Please use another one.";
    $match_found = true;
    break;
}
}

if(!$match_found)
{
fwrite($fh, $data . "\n");
// Set cookies for an hour
$hour = time() + 3600;
setcookie("username", $username, $hour);
//Redirect to home page
header("location: index.php");
}


}
//close the file

fclose($fh);


}


?>
```

Comment: Use PHP_EOL, which is a predefined constant that contains your operating platform's EOL character.

Comment: Looks like the problem was with this line:

$data = "$username:$password\n";

When I removed the \n after it, everything seemed to work.

Thanks for all your help everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to use is `\r\n`.

Comment: Looks like the problem was with this line:

$data = "$username:$password\n";

When I removed the \n after it, everything seemed to work.

Thanks for all your help everyone.

Answer (score 2):

For me only worked PHP_EOL (xampp on windows 7 php 5.3.8)

Comment: That was the answer for my fwrite() problem

Answer (score 0):

Use `PHP_EOL` for the platform dependent newline character. However, `\n` actually represents the newline character in the *NIX-world, but some windows editors denies to show them as newline (thats what happens in your case). You should consider using an other IDE and always use `\n` for compatibility (if the file should be usable on other platforms).

Answer (score 0):

"\r\n"   use this instead will work like a charm

Comment: can you give a brief may be?

Comment: This is nearly the same as the accepted answer. Just paraphrased. Please try to be more creative when answering an old question. Perhaps a different approach.